# c macro, array definition as parameter

Tags: c, arrays, macros

I have this method

```
foo_l(int *array, size_t l)
{
    /*
    code
    */
}
```

and I wrote this macro

```
#define foo(X) foo_l(X,sizeof(X)/sizeof(int))
```

So I can use them as follows

```
int main()
{
    int a[]={1,2,3};
    foo(a);
    return 0;
}
```

and avoid writing the length of the array every time.

**My question is**, can I extend my macro so it can handle something like

```
foo_l((int[]){1,2,3}, 3);
```

with an array declared in the function parameter field?

Because `foo((int[]){1,2,3})` doesn't work! I think that the problem is that the macro see `(int[]){1,2,3}` as a list of parameters and not as a unique parameter. Any Idea?

P.S. I'm pretty new to the macro world and I usually use c99.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When being passed to the preprocessor, the macro `foo((int[]){1,2,3})` fails because the preprocessor believes it provided 3 parameters instead of 1:

```
foo((int[]){1,2,3});
// is believed to be:
// Start of macro: foo(
// Parameter 1:    (int[]){1, 
// Parameter 2:    2, 
// Parameter 3:    3}
// End of macro:   );
```

So it doesn't compile and gives something like:

```
a.c: In function ‘main’:
a.c:15:23: error: macro "foo" passed 3 arguments, but takes just 1
     foo((int[]){1,2,3});
```

Adding another pair of parenthesis solves the problem:

```
// This shall work
foo(((int[]){1,2,3}));
```

#### EDITED:

Yes I guess this may not be a good design, since people like average programmers may be very likely to pass a pointer instead of an array type to your macro `foo`, and it would fail as @DwayneTowell points out.
Please be careful about this.
:)

Answer (score 0):

What you have suggested is not a good idea, because it will fail in cases like the following:

```
int a[] = {1,2,3,4};
int *b = a;
foo(b);        // becomes foo_l(b,sizeof(b)/(sizeof(int));
               // probably becomes foo_l(b,1)
```

In general the size parameter will be wrong if the first parameter is a pointer to an array instead of the array itself. Usually the expression will evaluate to 1, when sizeof(int *)==sizeof(int), which is very common but required by the standard.

Comment: I Agree. Also, It will not work for arrays that their size isn't known in compile time (allocated arrays). It *is* ok, though, to use this only for compile-time arrays.

Comment: The `sizeof` would fail since you're passing a pointer instead of an array type.

Comment: `sizeof(int *)` does not fail, it returns the size of a pointer, usually 4 or 8 bytes these days.

Comment: @DwayneTowell I see, but the OP wants to calculate the array length by `sizeof(X)/sizeof(int)`, doesn't he? That's what I mean by "fail".

Comment: @starrify, Right, we agree, but didn't I say that in my answer when I said "in general the size parameter will be wrong ..."?

Comment: @DwayneTowell I understand that, and I'm just pointing this out once again by commenting, cuz I don't think that's something that doesn't matter.

Comment: @DwayneTowell Oh sorry I thought you was posting it as an answer. You're pointing out the OP's problem, right? Yes I agree with you. However comment goes to comment, and I still don't think this is good as an answer.

Comment: @starrify, fair enough, I agree my "answer" could be considered off topic from a stict OP question point-of-view, but it was such a bad idea in general, I felt someone needed to answer it in a "there be dragons ahead" sort of way instead of blindly answering the exact question posed.